# How to query rows matching for a particular string?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, subquery, exists

This is  how table looks like and here Empid and idnumber were unique for each employee and also an employee can have multiple badges with different badge number.

[image]

Now,I want to filter employees whose badge start with  6542 and 3214, ie employees carrying both badge starting from 6542 and 3214

Thank u

**UPdate 1**

There are some records which is having only a single badge starting from 6542 or 3214 . but I want only employees who is carrying both badges .

Comment: GROUP BY, HAVING, COUNT DISTINCT

Comment: better put text than images

Answer (score 1):

Just use like on badge field

```
    Select empid, name 
    from TableName 
    where badge like '6542%' or badge like '3214%'
    group by empid, name
    having count(*)>1
```

Comment: "employees carrying both badge starting from 6542 and 3214"

Comment: This will return also employees whos carrying  one badge

Comment: ah ok, added goup by so

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: its not working as its returning employees having only badges starting from 6542%  or 3214 .

Comment: @coffemug looks like is ok for him

Answer (score 1):

Do a `GROUP BY`, use `HAVING` to ensure both badges:

```
select empid, name
from Table
where badge like '6542-%' or badge like '3214-%'
group by empid, name
having count(distinct badge) > 1
```

Or use `INTERSECT`:

```
select empid, name from Table where badge like '6542-%'
intersect
select empid, name from Table where badge like '3214-%'
```

Comment: @coffemug, which one?

Comment: both of them ….

Comment: If you had sample data as formatted text I could copy and paste and try for myself, but with an image that can't be done.

Comment: Does `select empid, name from Table where badge like '6542-%'` return anything?

Comment: it returns all the records starting from 6542%

Comment: And `select empid, name from Table where badge like '3214-%'` works too?

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
select empid from table_name where regexp_like(Badge,'^(6542)(.*)$')
intersect
select empid from table_name where regexp_like(Badge,'^(3214)(.*)$');
```

sql server equivalent:

```
select empid from table_name where PATINDEX ('^(6542)(.*)$',Badge)  !=0
intersect
select empid from table_name where PATINDEX ('^(6542)(.*)$',Badge)  !=0
```

Comment: "both badge" wanted.

Comment: @jarlh now its ok

Comment: its not supported I am in ms sql server

Answer (score 0):

We can use `COUNT DISTINCT` with `CASE` in `HAVING` as below

```
DECLARE @test AS TABLE(EMPID INT, Badge VARCHAR(50), idNumber INT, EName VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @test VALUES
(1148, '6542-74488', 66448, 'Adam Jhon'),
(1148, '642-8562', 66448, 'Adam Jhon'),
(1148, '3214-52874', 66448, 'Adam Jhon'),

(1149, '3214-45220', 209541, 'Tom Koyaski'),
(1150, '3214-23134', 63339, 'Shirin Abdulla'),
(1151, '3214-42355', 65498, 'Linda Jhon'),

(1151, '6542-2546', 65498, 'Linda Jhon'),
(1152, '3214-47632', 208673, 'Gayeth'),
(1153, '6542-73085', 83209, 'Maria Smith'),

(1153, '3214-58073', 65498, 'Maria Smith'),
(1154, '3214-26735', 208673, 'Ayan Jacob'),
(1155, '642-26739', 53959, 'Wo Li')

SELECT empid, Ename 
FROM @test 
WHERE badge LIKE '6542%' OR badge LIKE '3214%'
GROUP BY empid, Ename
HAVING COUNT (DISTINCT(CASE WHEN badge like '6542%' THEN 1 
                WHEN badge LIKE '3214%' THEN 2 END))>1
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
empid   Ename
1148    Adam Jhon
1151    Linda Jhon
1153    Maria Smith
```

Answer (score 0):

just simply do like this

```
    Select a.empid, a.name 
    from TableName as a
    inner join TableName as b on a.Empid = b.Empid and a.idnumber = b.idnumber and b.badge like '3214%'
    where a.badge like '6542%'
```